# Error restoring .net core 2.0 app upgraded to 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, tfs, azure-devops, dotnet-restore

Trying to VSTS build our .NET core application that we upgraded from 2.0 to 2.1.

When I build locally with SDK version 2.1.301 everything is fine. But the VSTS build is failing.

So I have a **global.json** to the root of the project failing added but this did not solve the issue:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.301"
  }
}
```

The error we are getting is this:

> 2018-06-29T10:40:44.2112663Z  2018-06-29T10:40:44.2112824Z
>   "D:\a\1\s\FooApp.Tests\FooApp.Tests.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
>   2018-06-29T10:40:44.2113005Z        (Restore target) -> 
>   2018-06-29T10:40:44.2113230Z          D:\a\1\s\FooApp\FooApp.csproj :
>   error NU1107: Version conflict detected for
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language. Reference the package directly
>   from the project to resolve this issue. 
>   [D:\a\1\s\FooApp.Tests\FooApp.Tests.csproj]
>   2018-06-29T10:40:44.2113815Z        D:\a\1\s\FooApp\FooApp.csproj :
>   error NU1107:  FooApp ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.1.1 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.1 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 2.1.1 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.1 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core 2.1.1 ->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating 2.1.1 ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language (>= 2.1.1) 
>   [D:\a\1\s\FooApp.Tests\FooApp.Tests.csproj]
>   2018-06-29T10:40:44.2114327Z        D:\a\1\s\FooApp\FooApp.csproj :
>   error NU1107:  FooApp -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language (= 2.1.0).
>   [D:\a\1\s\FooApp.Tests\FooApp.Tests.csproj]
>   2018-06-29T10:40:44.2114518Z

Here is the MyOwnApp.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Models\**" />
    <Content Remove="Models\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Models\**" />
    <None Remove="Models\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="2.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServerCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyOwnApp\MyOwnApp.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, for 2.1 and above you don't set the version for that

Comment: @DavidG  2.1.301 is the SDK version that corresponds to 2.1.1 while the error says that Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 was found. Perhaps the 2.1.301 SDK is not installed on the build server?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1#update-the-project-file-to-use-21-versions), but you might be right on the SDK not being installed.

Comment: Does that error occur only on the *build server*? Is the latest SDK installed on the build server?

Comment: @DavidG the error insists that 2.1.0 was found while the project requires 2.1.1

Comment: @DavidG check the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" package version. It's 2.1.1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos downgraded to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.1.0
Same issue on the build server. But restores and builds fine on my PC

Comment: *Don't* downgrade the package - your entire project targets 2.1.1. Downgrading a single package won't solve issues with all the other 2.1.1 packages. Install the 2.1.301 SDK on the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the SDK 2.1.301 SDK isn't installed on the TFS server. 2.1.301 corresponds to .NET Core 2.1.1

The package contains a reference to :

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
```

As the error says, this package ends up requiring the 2.1.1 version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language`. The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package found on the build server though is 2.1.0.

The solution is to install the 2.1.301 SDK on the server

**UPDATE**

If VSTS doesn't have the latest SDK version, it can be installed following the steps shown [here](https://cmatskas.com/working-with-the-latest-net-core-version-in-vsts/):

1. Add the `.NET Core Tool Installer` task as the first task in the build process and specify the SDK version. In this case it's `2.1.301`
2. Add the `Nuget Tool Installer` right after it.

These steps should install the correct versions of the SDK and NuGet

Comment: ok, so I am working on Visualstudio.com Team Services. Can I install it there, or do I have to wait for Microsoft to do it?

Comment: You can specify the SDK in the build definition. This was [asked here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/problem-restore-ef-core-2-1-1-in-vsts-hosted-vs2017/4405) and [explained here](https://cmatskas.com/working-with-the-latest-net-core-version-in-vsts/). You can add a `.NET Core Installer Task` in the build definition and specify `2.1.301` as the version

Comment: adding the step to install the 2.1.301 SDK did the trick. Many thanks for your help